# Adding navigation to HTML table in textarea

Tags: spotfire

I have an index page which provides information about the other pages in my analysis and the visualizations inside those pages built using an HTML table. I am able to add button to navigate to the desired page, however I would like to know if it is possible to add a hyperlink to the other pages rather than a button.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Instead of adding a button as an action control add a link as an action control.

You can do this by Insert Action Control > Control Type > Link, then add the pages you want to jump to in the Available Actions settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can create hyperlinks in the text area. They can be found in the Action control.

Edit the text area. 
Insert Action control.
Select link as control type. 
In Available Action Settings, you will get a list of all pages which are present in your analysis.

You can add that page and can make the navigation functionality.